# Outlook VBA: Compare every appointment date in a recurring pattern with spreadsheet data

Tags: vba, outlook, recurring, recurring-events

I want to find out a way to compare every recurring appointment date in a recurrent pattern with the data in a spreadsheet using a loop, so as to create a irregular recurrent pattern. How can this be realized? thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried/found so far. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The [GetRecurrencePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868441(v=office.15).aspx) method of the AppointmentItem class returns a [RecurrencePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863458.aspx) object that represents the recurrence attributes of an appointment. It provides the [GetOccurrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862727(v=office.15).aspx) method which returns a specific instance of the AppointmentItem object on the specified date. So, you can use the data listed on the spreadsheet and try to find a corresponding ocurrence in Outlook. Note, the *GetOccurrence* method generates an error if no appointment of that series exists on the specified date.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene mentioned, you can only pass a date to the `GetOccurrence` method in the Outlook Object Model, so it is your responsibility to figure out the days on which an appointment occurs - you will need to programmatically expand the recurrence pattern as well as use the `RecurrencePattern.Exceptions` collection to take into account modified occurrences.

You can of course loop through all dates in a given range and catch exceptions raised by `GetOccurrence` for the dates which the appointment does not occur.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), its implementation of the [RDORecurrencePattern](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDORecurrencePattern.htm).`GetOccurrence` method allows to pass an integer index (as well as a date), which means you can simply loop through all recurrences (as long as it is not a recurrence with no end date).